# Python - Try-except loop - Referencing time delay as exception

Tags: python, selenium, try-except

I'm attempting to code a try-except loop that refreshes a webpage if it fails to load. Here's what I've done so far:

```
driver.get("url")

while True:
    try:
        <operation>
    except:
        driver.refresh()
```

I want to set this loop up so that if 5 seconds elapse and the operation is not executed (presumably because the page did not load), it attempts to refresh the page. Is there an exception we can incorporate in `except` that catches the time delay?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616630/time-out-decorator-on-a-multprocessing-function

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading this post [Timeout function if it takes too long to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281850/timeout-function-if-it-takes-too-long-to-finish).

The gist of it is that you can use signals to interrupt the code and raise an error, which you then catch.

In you example:

```
def _handle_timeout(signum,frame):
    raise TimeoutError("Execution timed out")

driver.get("url")
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)   

while True:
    try:
        signal.alarm(<timeout value>)
        <operation>
        signal.alarm(0) 
    except:
        driver.refresh()
```

You can test this with the following snippet:

```
import time
import signal

def _handle_timeout(signum,frame):
    raise TimeoutError("Execution timed out")

def test(timeout,execution_time):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, _handle_timeout)
    try:
        signal.alarm(timeout)
        time.sleep(execution_time)
        signal.alarm(0)
    except:
        raise
    else:
    print "Executed successfully"
```

This will raise an error when `execution_time > timeout`.

As noted here in [Python signal don't work even on Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16371421/python-signal-dont-work-even-on-cygwin) the above code will not work on windows machines.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. However, I'm not able to get signal.SIGALRM to function on Python 3.3.4. I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'SIGALRM'`

Comment: Added a line to the answer, as this is an important point for others too.

Comment: Also, this blog post is required reading on the subject: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/22/how-not-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-computation-in-python/