# Restart a process if running longer than x amount of minutes

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing

I have a program that creates a multiprocessing pool to handle a webextraction job. Essentially, a list of product ID's is fed into a pool of 10 processes that handle the queue. The code is pretty simple:

```
import multiprocessing

num_procs = 10

products = ['92765937', '20284759', '92302047', '20385473', ...etc]

def worker():
    for workeritem in iter(q.get, None):
        time.sleep(10)
        get_product_data(workeritem)
        q.task_done()
    q.task_done()

q = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()

procs = []

for i in range(num_procs):
    procs.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=worker))
    procs[-1].daemon = True
    procs[-1].start()

for product in products:
    time.sleep(10)
    q.put(product)

q.join()

for p in procs:
    q.put(None)

q.join()

for p in procs:
    p.join()
```

The `get_product_data()` function takes the product, opens an instance of Selenium, and navigates to a site, logs in, and collects the details of the product and outputs to a csv file. The problem is, randomly (literally... it happens at different points of the website's navigation or extraction process) Selenium will stop doing whatever it's doing and just sit there and stop doing it's job. No exceptions are thrown or anything. I've done everything I can in the `get_product_data()` function to get this to not happen, but it seems to just be a problem with Selenium (i've tried using Firefox, PhantomJS, and Chrome as it's driver, and still run into the same problem no matter what).

Essentially, the process should never run for longer than, say, 10 minutes. Is there any way to kill a process and restart it with the same product id if it has been running for longer than the specified time?

This is all running on a Debian Wheezy box with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your code using `multiprocessing.Pool` and the [`timeout()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616630/time-out-decorator-on-a-multprocessing-function) [suggested by @VooDooNOFX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26517701/4279). Not tested, consider it an executable pseudo-code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import signal
from contextlib import closing
from multiprocessing import Pool

class Alarm(Exception):
    pass

def alarm_handler(*args):
    raise Alarm("timeout")

def mp_get_product_data(id, timeout=10, nretries=3):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarm_handler) #XXX could move it to initializer
    for i in range(nretries):
        signal.alarm(timeout) 
        try:
            return id, get_product_data(id), None
        except Alarm as e:
            timeout *= 2 # retry with increased timeout
        except Exception as e:
            break
        finally:
            signal.alarm(0) # disable alarm, no need to restore handler
    return id, None, str(e) 

if __name__=="__main__":
   with closing(Pool(num_procs)) as pool:
       for id, result, error in pool.imap_unordered(mp_get_product_data, products):
           if error is not None: # report and/or reschedule
              print("error: {} for {}".format(error, id))
   pool.join()
```

Comment: I seem to be getting an import error on `from functools import closing`. It seems the `closing` function doesn't exist in functools. I tried this on both Windows and Debian.

Comment: @crookedleaf: thank you for noticing. It is a stdlib function. It should be in `contextlib` instead. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Everything imports now, but i'm getting an exception o the `pool.imap_unordered()` function: `for id, result, error in pool.imap_unordered(mp_get_product_data, products):`
  `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 655, in next`
    `raise value`
`TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: Consider the answer to be a pseudo-code. You should be able to fix such errors yourself. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ask Selenium to wait an explicit amount of time, or wait for some implicit DOM object to be available. [Take a quick look at the selenium docs about that](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits-reference).

From the link, here's a process that waits `10 seconds` for the DOM element `myDynamicElement` to appear.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait # available since 2.4.0
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC # available since 2.26.0

ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))
except TimeoutException as why:
    # Do something to reject this item, possibly by re-adding it to the worker queue.
finally:
    ff.quit()
```

If nothing is available in the given time period, a `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException` is raised, which you can catch in a try/except loop like above.

**EDIT**

Another option is to ask `multiprocessing` to timeout the process after some amount of time. This is done using the built-in library `signal`. [Here's an excellent example of doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616630/time-out-decorator-on-a-multprocessing-function), however it's still up to you to add that item back into the work queue when you detect a process has been killed. You can do this in the `def handler` section of the code.

Comment: I have tried this same thing in many ways. The problem isn't always finding an element. For example, the problem has occurred after the element has been found and extracted, and the driver is supposed to navigate to a different page, but it never even attempts to process the next `driver.get()` command. Other times it finds a link, extracts the link text, then clicks it... it extracts the text (so it finds the element), but never even attempts to click the link. It really does happen at completely random points, and is processing about 16,000 searches a day.

Comment: @crookedleaf: Edited answer to show `signal` option. It's tricky to get right, but will 100% work in all cases.

Comment: Awesome! The `signal` option seems to work perfect. I just tested it on a test function that counts to 100, pausing after one second, and it kills it after 10 seconds, before it can get to 100. Now the trick will just be to figure out how to send the product ID back to the queue to be re-ran.